# Organizing technical documents and reports

Tags: productivity

At my university, I work on an aircraft design project. I’m building a fairly hefty collection of technical and design reports I’ve written as well as documents about things I’m trying to research to help with my design.

How can I organize these documents in a professional and a formal manner? I’m thinking of something like a document numbering system with hierarchy. For example, I’d like the numbering scheme to reflect document type (technical report, research findings, data, calculations, CAD drawings) and aircraft element (control systems, control surfaces, wing, landing gear, etc).

Answer (score 1):

It might help to add a few details to enable specific constructive responses. What is the purpose for organizing the documents: personal use, internal use within your team/department, public but less formal use such as your personal webpage, public and more formal use such as website of your research group, or inclusion in CV?

Each of these uses is aligned with different (though possibly overlapping) audiences, and might imply different approaches for what and how to present, what to highlight or omit, etc. etc.

So, first I recommend to organize your organizing needs/priorities, then address details.

A few general ideas, with regard to organizing in "professional/formal manner":

**Personal use:** There are tools such as Mendeley that can be helpful for figuring out and experimenting with ways to categorize the documentation. Mendeley can be leveraged for open/public access to materials as well as private use (e.g. uploading citations but not actual attachments).

**Research team website:** collaborate with your team to determine what might be worth sharing publicly (beyond what has already been made available). For instance, you might collectively decide that adding some previously un-shared white papers/tech reports, or even datasets might "fill out" the public profile of the group's research and allow the team to cite/reference these resources.

**Personal website:** Regardless of whether you make the material available on a collaborative formal webpage of your department/group, I see no problem with also featuring a few technical reports/white papers that you have authored or co-authored on your personal department page. Technically, if you work for a public university and unless your research is classified, your research output is in the public domain and you should be able to enable public access to it without any negative consequences. (There may be other specific caveats around this in each case, but you need to explore those and use your best judgment).

**CV:** In my experience, citing technical reports or white papers in your CV is totally acceptable and could serve to boost your research track record. Since tech reports are not typically externally peer reviewed, a safe approach is to place them in a separate dedicated section, e.g. "Technical Reports."

Finally, there are numerous sites out there such as Mendeley, Academia.edu, ResearchGate, etc. The sites differ in functionality, target audiences (e.g. more hard vs. more social sciences) and visibility/uptake within a given discipline. Here is a fairly complete listing as a starting point:
http://connectedresearchers.com/online-tools-for-researchers/. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the great response despite my lack of detail. Specifically, the reports are currently for my own usage but in the future, should I continue the work further with a team, I should like to be able to have the reports available and organized for easy reference. Additionally, some of the reports may be shared in the aircraft design community.

Comment: The research, however, will be kept for personal use and reference. For example, I might put together a table of certain trends for reference during my design work. I might also put together a document that summarizes my findings from the Internet and the literature for a certain topic. More specifically, I could certainly use something such as a reference book or manual that is quite common in the scientific and engineering communities except this book would be filled with content that I have put together based on data and information I've founded online and in literature.

Comment: @user26358, Thanks for clarification, you might also want to add this to your original question above so it's clearly visible to future readers. Personal organization seems to be highly dependent on preferences of the individual, for some people a clean folder structure in Windows may be enough while for others it is necessary to use a spreadsheet like Excel, or document management tool like Mendeley. Also tools such as Microsoft's OneNote are fairly popular due to their flexibility for arranging/rearranging material. If you do find a system that works for you, please update/share here!